# If $\frac{dy}{dx}= 1-x-xy$, find the solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a really short question, so I can’t write much here. Basically, I am not able to separate the variables, and I don’t know how to reduce it to that form either. What should I substitute in order to solve it?

Comment: Have you worked with integrating factors?

Comment: Search "linear first order ODE"

Comment: @Chinny84 does that involve variable separation?

Comment: @Aditya there is a solution by Ramanujan that goes through it. It is much easier to solve with I.F.

Comment: my only comment is that you are left with error function which is fairly complex topic given the level of the ode. Is there are an issue/typo with the original ode?

Comment: @Chinny84 there is no typo in the question, but I think you might be right. It’s too complex for the level I am working at. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to solve $$y'=1-x-xy$$
where $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $y=y(x)$.

Now, we  can see that $$y'+xy=-x+1$$
Let, $\mu(x)=\exp\left(x \right)=e^\frac{x^{2}}{2}$
Multiply both sides by $\mu(x)$ and then substitute $e^{x^{2}/2}x=\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{x^{2}/2}\right)$  So, we have $$ \frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{x^{2}/2}y\right)=-e^{x^{2}/2}(x-1) \implies \int \frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{x^{2}/2}y\right) dx =\int -e^{x^{2}/2}(x-1)dx$$ Solving we get, $$e^{x^{2}/2}y=-e^{x^{2}/2}+\sqrt{\pi/2} \text{erfi} \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right)+c$$
Therefore, $$\boxed{ y(x)=\frac{1}{e^{x^{2}/2}}\left( -e^{x^{2}/2}+\sqrt{\pi/2} \text{erfi} \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right)+c\right)}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= 1-x-xy$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+xy= 1-x$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx^2}\dfrac {dx^2}{dx}+xy= 1-x$$
$$2\frac{dy}{dx^2}+y= \dfrac 1x-1$$
$$2\frac{dy}{dv}+y= \dfrac 1 {\sqrt v}-1$$
$$2y'+y= \dfrac 1 {\sqrt v}-1$$
Where $v= x^2$.

Can you solve this one ?